# Escaping completion handler that takes optional argument sometimes crashes Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore, swift4

I have this code:

```
 func function(completion: @escaping (_ error: Error?) -> Void){
    getSomethingFromUrl {(result) in
        guard let documentData = result.property else {
            completion(nil) //crashes with error Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x102ba1774)
            return
        }
    }
}
```

sometimes it crashes on the **completion(nil) line**, with the error code

> Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x102ba1774)

I have no idea why it is crashing considering the argument is optional, and I am simply passing nil to it.

Here is the exact code that I am using to call the completion handler. It is in the completion block of a firestore transaction:

```
let docSizesRef = FirebaseHelper.References.firestoreReference.collection(FirestoreCollections.onlineUsers).document(FirestoreDocuments.documentSizeTracker)
                            FirebaseHelper.References.firestoreReference.runTransaction({ (transaction, errorPointer) -> Any? in
                                let docSizesDocument: DocumentSnapshot
                                do {
                                    try docSizesDocument = transaction.getDocument(docSizesRef)
                                } catch let fetchError as NSError {
                                    errorPointer?.pointee = fetchError
                                    return nil
                                }

                                let oldCount = docSizesDocument.data()?[documentIdToWriteTo] as? Int ?? 0

                                transaction.updateData([documentIdToWriteTo: oldCount + 1], forDocument: docSizesRef)
                                return nil
                            }) { (object, error) in
                                completion(error)
                                if let error = error {
                                    print("Transaction failed: \(error)")
                                } else {
                                    print("Transaction successfully committed!")
                                }
                            }
```

Andhere is the code that deals with completion

```
func addUserToOnlineDocs(){
                User.shared.managers.accountManager.addToOnlineDocs(completion: { (error) in
                    if let error = error{
                        self.createTwoButtonAlert(title: AlertErrors.Account.Titles.errorAddingToOnlineList, message: error.localizedDescription, rightButtonText: self.retryButton, leftButtonText: self.ignoreButton, rightButtonStyle: .cancel, leftButtonStyle: .default, completion: { (buttonPressed) in
                            if buttonPressed == self.retryButton{
                                connectionSetup()
                            }
                        })
                        return
                    }
                    self.loadingCompleteDispatchGroup.leave()
                })
            }
```

could it be to do with the transaction calling the completion handler multiple times?

Comment: What's the code of the parameter completion?

Comment: just doing if let error = error{ code.. }else{leave dispatch group}

Comment: I think its sometthing to do with  the dispatch group leaving not matching the enters

Comment: There's no dispatch group in your code. Please show the exact code which can reproduce the issue.

Comment: This is very interesting. Please also post the code that is calling your completion handler.

Comment: updated the question

Comment: Thanks for updating, but I cannot find something sure with filling hidden parts of your code. What happens if you change `completion(error);if let error = error {/**/} else {/**/}` to `if let error = error {completion(error);/**/} else {completion(nil);/**/}` ?

Comment: I tried and it gives the same error, as it should since it's the same logic

Comment: I needed to confirm that, as you are hiding many relevant parts of your code. And the result is telling us we need to explore other possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add ;
else { completion(nil); return }